# Has someone put together the story of 'The Hero of Ages'?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

In the Mistborn books by Brandon Sanderson, the chapters are inter-cut with snippets about the hero of ages and his quest. I've been listening in with Audible to the stories, but I honestly think I'd struggle to piece the information together if I had the books. Has someone summarised the information revealed somewhere?

It's mostly the second book I'm struggling with (which is where I've gotten to), the summary of Alendi, on the mistborn wikia is enough to refresh my memory on the first book snippets.

The thing that confuses me the most, I suppose is pulling apart all the different people talking. *Which is which?* Is there a clear distinction for each book?

Comment: I don't recall the HoA snippets being too hard to follow in the books, but it has been a couple of years since I read them.

Comment: It will make sense at the end of the trilogy.  I would recommend that people not read a summary of that except in the manner presented in the books, because that story from the past is tied to the present.

Comment: @BBlake I'm most of the way through book two, and I don't want to be spoiled. If the answer is "It's not meant to make sense yet" then so be it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Final Empire quotes are from

> [Alendi's diary](http://coppermind.net/wiki/Alendi%27s_journal) of events up to his death by the Lord Ruler (Rashek)

The Well of Ascension quotes are from

> [Kwaan's inscription](http://coppermind.net/wiki/Kwaan%27s_inscription) in the Conventical of Seran (where Sazed and Marsh visit)

The Hero of Ages quotes are from

> the [Words of Founding](http://coppermind.net/wiki/Words_of_Founding), the books left behind by Sazed after the Final Ascension, one of the books includes the [letter](http://coppermind.net/wiki/Sazed%27s_note) read by Spook in the epilogue.

Comment: In retrospect, I should have done this instead of hinting at it. Yaaaaay spoiler blocks!

Answer (score 1):

In the later Mistborn books, not all of the snippets at the tops of the chapters are from the ancient diary. There are at least two ancient characters and one modern character whose writings appear in those snippets over the course of the series.

And one request - this issue brushes massive spoilers, please be circumspect!

Comment: In the book is it clear who is talking when? In the audiobook I'm struggling to pick out who is who.

Comment: Certainly by the end of a given book you can tell who was who, but sometimes it's unclear for a few chapters, because they say something you don't expect to hear.

Comment: IIRC All the snippets in Well of Ascension were from Kwaan.  All the snippets from The Final Empire were from Alendi's diary.

Comment: @Corwin01 that's excellent! Answer?

Comment: Ok, so I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The snippets in The Final Empire are all from Alendi's diary.

The snippets in The Well of Ascension all come from Kwaan's inscription on the steel plate.